# How to make Negated scanset of scanf() work in a loop?

Tags: c

Here is my C code. `Scanset` of `scanf()` does not work within the for loop . It takes only one value for string even in loop. If I replace  `scanset` of `scanf()` with `gets()` it works. How to make this `scanset`   work in a loop?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
     char str[128];
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<2;i++)
     {
         printf("Enter a string with spaces: ");
         scanf("%[^\n]s", str);

         printf("You entered: %s\n", str);
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: change `scanf("%[^\n]s", str);` to `scanf("%127[^\n]%*c", str);`

Comment: @user3121023:  scanf(" %127[^\n]", str); it dint worked

Comment: What is a "scanset"?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: your solution worked, can you please explain why and how?

Comment: Keep in mind that `%[^\n]` fails when the first character to be read is a `\n`

Comment: @NitinTripathi `%*c` drop(read skip) one character(`\n`) because next `%[^\n]` don't allow `\n`

Comment: @NitinTripathi Are you sure you added the leading space before the `%` as shown in user3121023's comment?

Comment: Hu, I see. Who invented this expression ... :-S @CoolGuy I'd consider this a "* bracket expression*" (see `man 7 regex`).

Comment: @user3121023: I am so sorry i missed the space before %127.. it worked

Comment: @CoolGuy: thanks for notifying it :)

Comment: @user3121023   [Thanku so much . It worked . But can you please explain me the logic ?]

Comment: @alk It is in the standard as well.

Comment: @CoolGuy: scanf(" %[^\n]s", str); even this works... no need of 127 or anything else.. just **space** is needed before %[^\n]s.. why and how?

Comment: @NitinTripathi The 127 is there to prevent buffer overflows. That is, `scanf` will scan a maximum of 127 characters (+1 for the NUL-terminator) thus preventing overflows. As for the space, it scans and discards all whitespace characters, if any, until the first non-whitespace character.

Comment: @CoolGuy Can you explain what is the importance of space ??? How is it working with space ??

Comment: @CoolGuy: thanks for explaining it. i never heard of %[ format before. I think i should start reading the notes of scanf again :) :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this quiz:  User types <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> and code is

```
scanf("%[AB]", buf1);
scanf("%[AB]", buf2);
```

What goes into `buf1`?
What goes into `buf2`?

`scanf("%[AB]", buf1);` --> `"AB"` is store in `buf1` and returns 1 indicating 1 field successfully scanned.  `scanf("%[AB]", buf2);` -->  `buf2` remains unchanged, nothing is put in it and `'C'` and `'\n'` remain in `stdin`.  The return value of 0 indicating failure to save data, but something is in `stdin`.

The same thing happens with <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
scanf("%[^\n]", buf3);
scanf("%[^\n]", buf4);
```

`"DEF"` is store in `buf3`.  But `buf4` remains unchanged, nothing is put in it and `'\n'`,  `'G'`, `'H'`, `'I'` and `'\n'` remain in `stdin`.

---

OP code fails because `'\n'` is never consumed by `scanf("%[^\n]s", str);`.

---

The closest acceptable general method is

```
*str = 0;  // Terminate s in case only \n entered
if (scanf("%127[^\n]", str) != 1) Handle_EOF();
scanf("%1*[\n]"); // consume next character if it is a \n
```

---

Using a negated scanset, or any scanset, to read a line in a poor general purpose solution.
Use `fgets()` or `getline()` (*nix) instead.

```
fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0; // To lop off a potential trailing \n
```

---

Other approaches:

1. `scanf(" %127[^\n]", str);` first scans in all leading white-space and throws them away, then it scans non-`'\n'` characters into `str`.  This does not allow leading spaces in `str`.
2. `scanf("%127[^\n]%*c", str);` reads in nothing if the first character is `'\n'`.  `str` left unchanged.  A repeated call will also have the same problem.
3. `scanf(" %[^\n]s", str);` fails like #1.  Also: the 's' is pointless - remove it.